# Keras model (tensorflow backend) trains perfectly well in python 3.5 but very bad in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, model, keras, python-3.5

**What I try to do**
I'm trying to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) for image-detection using Keras with Tensorflow-GPU as backend in Python 2.7, since I need to use it with ROS kinetic, which only supports Python 2.7 (and not 3.5). My model is a Sequential (code see down below).

**What I am using**
Pycharm-Community 2018.1.4
Keras 2.2.0
Tensorflow-GPU 1.8.0
60000 input images, 100x100 pixels (3 channels), 3 classes ("train_set")
20000 evaluation images, same dimensions ("evaluation_set")

**What works**
When training the model on my train_set using **Python 3.5** and evaluate it using Python 3.5 it works perfectly fine (train_accuracy: 0.99874, evaluation_accuracy: 0.9993).

**What does not work**
When training the model on my train_set using **Python 2.7** and evaluate it using Python 2.7 my accuracy drops drastically (train_accuracy: 0.695, evaluation_accuracy: 0.543), which is not much more than guessing on 3 classes (which would be 0.3333).
I also tried training the model in Python 3.5 and load it in Python 2.7 for evaluation and prediction, but the results are as worse as before.

In all cases I am using the exact same code:

```
def build_model(training_input):
    model = Sequential()  
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)) # Add some layers

    model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

def train():
    input_training = np.array(input_training_list)    # input_training_list is a list containing the imagedata
    labels_training = np.array(label_training_list)    # label_training_list is a list containing the labels corresponding to the imagedata
    model = create_model(input_training)
    history = model.fit(input_training, labels_training, epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=20)
    model.save(model_directory + "my_model.h5")

def evaluation():
    input_evaluation = np.array(input_evaluation_list)
    labels_evaluation = np.array(label_evaluation_list)
    model = load_model(model_directory + "my_model.h5")
    loss, acc = model.evaluate(input_evaluation, labels_evaluation, batch_size=1)
```

I heard that many people have issues loading the same model in different Sessions(), using different computers or different versions of Python. But here the same architecture gives completely different results in both Python versions.

Comment: What happens if you just `model.save_weights()` and then rebuild the model in Python 2 and just `model.load_weights()`?

Comment: @nuric I just tried `model.save_weights("my_weights.h5")` in my working Python 3.5 script, build the same model/architecture in Python 2.7 and loaded the weights into that model `model.load_weights("my_weights.h5")` . But the results don't change. What confuses me is that even training the model in Python 2.7 gives such bad results.

Comment: I would update packages to latest versions in both platforms and try again.

Comment: @nuric All packages on both platforms are up to date, I just retried everything and nothing changes.

Comment: It might be the data -- how do you get it and have you checked it is consistent for both versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem (thanks to user1735003 for the tip regarding my data).
The reason for my bad results was a wrong data-implementation due to the **differences** regarding **Python 2.x and Python 3.x**. When implementing my image-data I use

```
for i in range(len(evaluation_files)):
    input_evaluation = np.divide(ndimage.imread(evaluation_files[i]), 255)
```

But here is the Problem: In Python 3.x this works perfectly fine, since a division of two integers results in a float, but in Python 2.x the result is an integer as well, so my input_evalution list only consists of zeros. I need to **divide by 255.0** (make the result a float).

```
input_evaluation = np.divide(ndimage.imread(evaluation_files[i]), 255.0)
```

Alternatively import `division` from `__future__` to get floating point results from integer divisions already in python 2.

```
from __future__ import division
```

There are some mayor differences when using Python 2.x or Python 3.x which you can see very nicely for example on http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html .

I also managed training my model on Python 3.5, save it using `model.save('my_model')` and load it in Python 2.7 using `keras.models.load_model('my_model')`, which works perfectly fine.

One would also easily just save the weights using `model.save_weights('my_weights')`, create a new model of the same architecture(!) in Python 2.7 and load the weights into that model using `model.load_weights('my_weights')`, but since just loading the model itself works perfectly fine that way is much easier.